# MySQL Combine Two Tables Sum By Month

Tags: mysql, union

I have two tables stok_in, and stok_out

Here is the sample
[image: Table Stok_in]

And this for table #2 (stok_out)

[image: Stok_out]

How Do I get the result for sum with group by monthname

the result should be like

[image: Wrong Result]

The result was 4 rows what I need is

Sum(jml_out) | Monthname(tggl_out) | Sum(jml_in) | Monthname(tggl_in)

I am using this query but wrong of course

```
select sum(jml_out) ,monthname(tggl_out) from stok_out group by monthname(tggl_out)
union 
select sum(jml_in) ,monthname(tggl_in) from stok_in group by monthname(tggl_in)
```

Comment: Why not just make 2 queries and join them in code? Why overly complicate it? The answer below has subqueries which will use __way__ more resources than necessary. If you really have to get it that way from MySQL, you can use a JOIN instead of a UNION

Comment: can you give some insight ? if I use inner join, things not as expected.

Comment: Get rid of the `union` and run the 2 queries separately. When you get the results back, combine them in whatever programming languages you are using. That last part should be simple

Answer (score -1):

Define some aliases for your columns, and do a group by on the result:

```
select M, sum(S)
from (
   select 
      - sum(jml_out) as S,
      monthname(tggl_out) as M
   from stok_out 
   group by monthname(tggl_out)

   union ALL

   select 
      sum(jml_in) ,
      monthname(tggl_in) 
   from stok_in 
   group by monthname(tggl_in)
) x
group by x.M
```

Note: I also change union to `UNION ALL`, and added a minus sign before `sum(jml_out)`.

EDIT: Because of the need of 4 output columns...

```
select 
   sumOUt, 
   monthOut,
   sumIn,
   monthIn
from (
select 
   sum(jml_out) as sumOut,
   monthname(tggl_out) as monthOut
from stok_out 
group by monthname(tggl_out)) x
inner join (
   select 
      sum(jml_in) sumIn,
      monthname(tggl_in) monthIn 
   from stok_in 
   group by monthname(tggl_in)) y on x.monthOut = y.monthIn
```

NOTE/WARNING: This goes OK because all months do have values for each month. If that is not the case, then this will fail.

EDIT: If you have missing month, then you can do something like (if you have MySQL8.0 or above):

```
WITH recursive cte as (
   select min(M) as MinM, max(M) as MaxM from (select month(tggl_in) as M from stock_in union select month(tggl_out) from stock_out) x 
   union all
   select MinM+1,MaxM FROM cte where MinM < MaxM)
SELECT 
   -- cte.MinM,
   o.sum_out as jml_out, 
   o.mn as month_out, 
   i.sum_in as jml_in, 
   i.mn as month_in
from cte
LEFT JOIN (SELECT month(tggl_out) m, monthname(tggl_out) as mn, sum(jml_out) as sum_out from stock_out group by 1,2) o ON o.m = cte.MinM
LEFT JOIN (SELECT month(tggl_in) m, monthname(tggl_in) as mn, sum(jml_in) as sum_in from stock_in group by 1,2) i ON i.m = cte.MinM
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16c32693cab773b552a3e5c037da0bf9)

or [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=15c8ebd8fb2dd16c14867f07f0ce1aab) with missing months.

Comment: well.. thanks, the result not as expected, what I expect is 4 columns consists of 2 columns (jml_in, monthname) from stok_in, and last 2 columns (jml_out, monthname) from stok_out..

Comment: nice, the side effect is each month must have value, that is the downside, but let me figure how to make sure each month has value. really appreciated this answer

Comment: Added an example for returning 4 columns, which also works if not all months do exist in stock_in or stock_out.